# clone from a git repo and commit to a new repository

Tags: git, github

I've created a skeleton theme for the Ghost blogging engine. And committed this to a github repo, I want to be able to clone this repo as a new theme.

```
$ cd ghost/content/themes
git clone https://github.com/StyxOfDynamite/styx_ghost_theme.git new_theme_name

$ ls -l
new_theme_name
```

this successfully creates a new theme, a copy of the base theme, however I want to change this and commit the new changes to a different repository not overwrite the changes to the base template....

How do I achieve this?

Comment: On GitHub, since June 2019, you now have repository templates: See "[Can I create a new repository out of an existing repository but rename it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56484678/6309)".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have cloned your repository ... Now you should go under `new_theme_name` directory.

Here, if you type the command `git remote`, you should have `origin` displayed on your screen. Then, knowing your other repository url, you just have to type :

```
git remote set-url origin the_url_of_your_repo_here
```

*Et voila !* This is much nicer than removing the whole `.git` directory. This way you will keep the history of the repository you had initially cloned.

If you use *SSH* to push (which is usually the case), don't forget to generate a pair of (public, private) key with `ssh-keygen` and to let the remote server know your public key.

Comment: Awesome! Tks dude, it helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, then you've already cloned a base skeleton repo and you would like to use it for a new project and create a new repo from that.

You'll just need to delete the .git directory after you've cloned it, and then run `git init` to create a new repo with those files.

After running `git init`, just do `git commit -a` to commit all of the cloned files to source control.

You can also look into using git submodules which may be appropriate for what you need to do.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: How do I then push the newly committed repo to github?

Comment: The answer doesn't explain how to set up a remote for the local repository, which is basically the OP question. Moreover, the side effect of losing the whole development history of the original project violates the Open Source philosophy. I don't like it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Do you care if the history of the base theme is in the history of the new theme? If the presence of the history doesn't bother you, then you can to go to github.com and create a new repository with a different name (let's say `new_theme_name`).

Then, cd into your `new_theme_name` directory and change the URL that the `origin` remote is pointing to from the base theme's repo to the one you just created:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/StyxOfDynamite/new_theme_name.git
```

Then when you commit changes and push, the changes will go to the new_theme_name repo instead.